# Determine the Supremum and Infimum of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given $S =\{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m}, n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$. 
Determine the supremum and infimum of $S$.

Is it true that the infimum of $S$ is $-\infty$ when $\sqrt{n}$ is equal to $1$ (minimum)  and $\sqrt{m}$ is equal to $\infty$ and its supremum is equal to $\infty$ when $n$ is maximum ($\infty$)  and $m$ is minimum ($1$)? Can we just solve this by this approachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the idea is just to show that

for n=1

$$\lim_{m\to+\infty} \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m} = -\infty$$

and for m=1

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m} = +\infty$$